# Missing template when attaching pdf to actionmailer and wicked pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, wicked-pdf

I get Missing template when trying to send an email with a pdf attachment:

Controller

```
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do 
        render pdf: "job card ##{@bike_service.id} - #{DateTime.now}", :template => 'bike_services/show.html.erb' # Excluding ".pdf" extension.
      end
    end

    BikeServiceMailer.job_card_pdf_email(BikeService.last.id).deliver_now
  end
```

Mailer

```
    def job_card_pdf_email(bike_service_id)
        bike_service = BikeService.find(bike_service_id)
        attachments["bike_service_#{bike_service.id}-#{DateTime.now}.pdf"] = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
        render_to_string(pdf: 'bike_service', template: File.join('app', 'views', 'bike_services', 'show.pdf.erb'), layout: 'pdf.html')
        )
        mail(to: todo.owner.email, subject: 'Your job card PDF is attached', bike_service: bike_service)
    end
```

The show.pdf.erb template is there already.

Comment: Can you please post the error message

Comment: @ReggieB 

`Missing template app/views/bike_services/show.pdf.erb with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :vtt, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :svg, :mpeg, :mp3, :ogg, :m4a, :webm, :mp4, :otf, :ttf, :woff, :woff2, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip, :gzip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/vangama/projects/mm-crm/app/views"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change the `render_to_string` line to either:

```
render_to_string(pdf: 'bike_service', template: File.join('bike_services', 'show.pdf.erb'), layout: 'pdf.html')
```

or

```
render_to_string(pdf: 'bike_service', template: Rails.root.join('app', 'views', 'bike_services', 'show.pdf.erb'), layout: 'pdf.html')
```

At the moment, I think the system is looking for `app/views/bike_services/show.pdf.erb` in `/Users/vangama/projects/mm-crm/app/views` which is effectively `/Users/vangama/projects/mm-crm/app/views/app/views/bike_services/show.pdf.erb` which doesn't exist.